# how to use mktime with "I" (summertime option)?

Tags: php, date, php-7, mktime

I wanted to code a script which returns true if the given date is in the summertime. So I found date("stuff" mktime) in the php [documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php). And there is a list of parameter strings. There it says: `"I (capital i)    Whether or not the date is in daylight saving time"`. Some lines below I found this example:

```
echo "July 1, 2000 is on a " . date("l", mktime(0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 2000));
```

That's why I wrote this in my script:

```
function summertime(string $date) : bool {
    $pieces = explode('-', $date);
    $year = (int) $pieces[0];
    $month = (int) $pieces[1];
    $day = (int) $pieces[2];

    return date("I", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year));
}

echo summertime("1981-07-07");
```

No matter which date I put in, it returns always false/0 what ever... I can't find the difference or mistake... FYI: I am using PHP 7.0.

Comment: Try setting timezone e.g. with `date_default_timezone_set`. Your current default timezone might be one which doesn't have summertime at all (e.g. UTC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in Markus Laire's comment, you probably need to set your timezone correctly. I'd also recommend using the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class. The examples below show how to set a specific timezone when creating a new date:

Example 1:

```
$tz = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin');
$date = new DateTime('1981-07-07', $tz);
echo $date->format('I');
// outputs '1'
```

Example 2:

```
$tz = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin');
$date = new DateTime('1981-01-01', $tz);
echo $date->format('I');
// outputs '0'
```